# emberjs handle dom event

Tags: ember.js

New to emberjs, after reading some article, I am confused with emberjs dom handle mechanism.

From the slide: http://www.lukemelia.com/blog/archives/2012/08/23/architecting-ember-js-apps/ page 41: we have 3 choice to handle dom event now:
1. ember dispatched event, such as: mouseDown.
2. action helper
3. In didInsertElement or other callback
And in Responding to Browser Events portion of doc: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.View.html we event have event manager.

My understanding is 
1. We should use action helper when action will cause application state change or fetch data 
2. Using didInsertElement for integration of other library such as flexslider(initialize)
3. Otherwise use ember dispatched event

Dose my understanding right? Is this the ember blessed way to handle dom event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Should help you understand more about the [Concepts](https://github.com/emberjs/website/blob/doc-refactor/source/guides/getting-started/core-concepts.md)